# Find the expression of $j_+$ and $j_-$operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, operators

I have just started to do exercises about quantum mechanics and I have some difficulties.

I have a particle with spin $j=1$ and the Hamiltonian is $H=\gamma(j_xj_y+j_y j_x)$ (where $\gamma$ is a constant).

I have to find the matricial form of $H$, its einginvalues and eigenvectors.

If I choose the basis that allows $j^2$ and $j_z$ to be diagonal, I can use the operators $j_+=j_x+ij_y$ and $j_-=j_x-ij_y$

Then I can write $j_xj_y+j_y j_x=\frac{1}{2i}(j_+^2-j^2_ -)$

But I have tried to find the matricial expression of $j_+$ and $j_-$ but haven't succeeded.. Can you help me?

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: @KyleKanos Please, could you explain me in which way I have to ask the question? Do I have to ask only in which way I can find the expression of j+ and j-? (so it will be more respondent to the point "Ask about the specific concept that gives you trouble"..) I have written all the problem only for clarity, I didn't ask to solve the entire problem...

Comment: You have to ask in such a way that you're not demanding us do your work for you. For instance, what is confusing you about $j_{\{x,y,+,-\}}$ that is preventing you from writing it in matrix form? Why not ask about that, rather than your current form?

Comment: @KyleKanos Ok, I have understood. In the comment to Timaeus' answer I have explained the difficulties that I have met. Next time I'll write them directy in the question. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define your $J_\pm$ in terms of $J_x$ and $J_y$ then you'll need to know those matrices.

If you consider $J_x=\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt 2}\left(\begin{matrix} 0&1&0\\
1&0&1\\
0&1&0\end{matrix}\right),$ and $J_y=\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt 2}\left(\begin{matrix} 0&-i&0\\
i&0&-i\\
0&i&0\end{matrix}\right)$ then you are done.

Alternatively you can define the $J_\pm$ by their direct action on a state $|m\rangle$ via $J_\pm|m\rangle=\hbar\sqrt{1(1+1)-m(m\pm 1)}|m\pm 1\rangle.$

This leads directly to $J_+=\hbar\left(\begin{matrix} 0&\sqrt{ 2-(0)(1)}&0\\
0&0&\sqrt {2-(-1)(0)}\\
0&0&0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $J_-=\hbar\left(\begin{matrix} 0&0&0\\
\sqrt{ 2-(1)(0)}&0&0\\
0&\sqrt{ 2-0(-1)}&0\end{matrix}\right).$

Then from those we can get $J_x$ via $J_x=(J_++J_-)/2$ and we can get $J_x$ via $J_x=(iJ_--iJ_+)/2.$

Its up to you to figure out which is your definition (or which connects to your definitions) then get the appropriate other one, and then find the eigenvectors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Timaeus! Before posting the question, I tried to find the matrix of $j_+$ using the action of $j_+$ on a state |j, m>:

$j_+|j,m>=\hbar \sqrt{(j-m)(j+m+1)} |j,m>$ (I imagine that this formula is analogous to yours, but I haven't understood the origin of 1(1+1).. is it $j(j+1)?$)

and I have obtained

$j_+|1,1>=\hbar \sqrt 0 |1,1>$; 

$j_+|1,0>=\hbar \sqrt 2 |1,0>$;

$j_+|1,-1>=\hbar \sqrt 2 |1,1>$ 

my problem is that I don't know to "build" the matrix.... thanks again!

Comment: @sunrise All the $j(j+1)-m(m\pm 1)$ stuff just gives $\sqrt 2$ since the $m=0$ and $m=-1$ are the only ones that get raised and they have $m(m+1)=0$ and the $m=0$ and $m=+1$ are the only ones that get lowered and they have $m(m-1)=0.$ All the $1\pm 1$ stuff is me just trying to zero out the right entries so it was all about the fact that the raised or lowered state is in the state $|m\pm 1\rangle.$

Comment: I'm sorry. I haven't understood, maybe I was not clear in the last question. I'll retry. I can write the matrix $j_+$ in this way: $j_+=\begin {pmatrix}  a & b&c\\d&e&f\\g&l&k\end{pmatrix}$. What do I have to put for the element $j+ _{i,l}$? (the element in the row $i$ and column $l$) Many thanks

Comment: @sunrise I edited the answer.